# JPA + websphere Cannot insert Record

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions, websphere-8

Below is my configuration of spring and spring_persistence.xml. The persist() Operation is not inserting the record. No error as well..

WAS 8.5 App server
Spring 3.1 
Hibernate 3.6.7

Please help !

```
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<context:annotation-config /> 

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager" >
    </bean>



<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property  name="persistenceUnitName" value="perstemplate"/>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/myspring_persistence.xml"/>
      </bean>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="perstemplate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <class>com.mycompany.EntityClass</class>
     </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Not sure it's the only problem, but since you're using JTA, the transaction-type shouldn't be RESOURCE_LOCAL, but JTA.

Comment: thanks, I am adding some websphere related properties as well in persistence properties..After I test them I will let you know..

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an TransactionManager from the Container you need to set the transaction-type to `JTA`.

Comment: No Errors in the log file : I could not see this as suspcious...JDBCContext.registerSynchronizationIfPossible(201)> TransactionFactory reported no active transaction; Synchronization not registered... Can I turn on some more deeper logging in hibernate..I already have  LOG level as <logger name="org.hibernate"><level value="trace" /></logger>